# Fetch data from another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am designing an Android App where I need to read data from URLs at various levels. I have successfully fetched the JSON data from URL using JSON Object and then I have displayed the location in a Map. I have used ASyncTask for this case, not Service.

I have a list of devices whose data is stored in a Database and using PHP I am fetching the data in a URL. When I click on Devices, I redirect to Maps but use another activity in between (Say Dummy Activity) for fetching the required data for that particular device. I do not display this Activity to the user. It is automatically redirected to Maps.

Now I would like to update the data on MapsActivity by calling the Dummy Activity for getting the required data from the URL and at the same time update the location on Android Maps by Animation.

I would like to use AsyncTask and not Service for this. The Maps Activity will keep querying for data as long as the user is on the Maps Activity page. Please, can anyone provide me with the code to get the data from one Activity without redirecting to the other? (In this case update data on Maps without redirecting to the Dummy Activity)

Here is my code for Maps Activity:

```
package altis.trackingapp.track;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    String latitude="";
    String longitude="";
    String imei;

    private static String url;
    String status;

    Double myLat=0.0;
    Double myLng=0.0;

    private String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        latitude=getIntent().getStringExtra("latitude");
        longitude=getIntent().getStringExtra("longitude");
        imei=getIntent().getStringExtra("imei");

        url = "http://139.162.37.96/track/api2/geteventstatus.php?imei="+imei;

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        new GetEventStatus().execute();

    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        myLat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        myLng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Lat:"+myLat+"\tLng:"+myLng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (myLat==0 && myLng==0) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Invalid Location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent dev = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DevicesNavActivity.class);
            startActivity(dev);
        }

        else if (myLat==null && myLng==null) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent dev = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DevicesNavActivity.class);
            startActivity(dev);
        }

        else {

            LatLng location = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);

            //Adding Marker to Location
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(location)
                    .title("Marker")
                    .snippet("My Marker")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));


            //Displaying the Info Window
            InfoWindowData info = new InfoWindowData();
            info.setName("Co-Ordinates of "+imei);
            info.setLatitude(latitude);
            info.setLongitude(longitude);

            CustomInfoWindowActivity customInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindowActivity(this);
            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow);

            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            m.setTag(info);
            m.showInfoWindow();


            // Add a marker in Location and move the camera
//            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker"));
            //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 17f));

            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Intent event = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EventGenerateActivity.class);
                    event.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
                    event.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
                    event.putExtra("imei",imei);
                    event.putExtra("status",status);
                    startActivity(event);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetEventStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr.trim().equals("1"))
                status = "1";
            else
                status = "0";

            Log.e(TAG, "Status: " +status);


            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent dev = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DevicesNavActivity.class);
        startActivity(dev);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: make Base Activity which is contact with your map and then extends all activity with your base activity.

Comment: Means I will call Base Activity from Maps and then in Base Activity will extend the Activities whose data is required by me?

Comment: And can you please tell from where should I call this Base Activity in my Maps Activity?

Comment: Activities will extends base activity whose data required by you. and the option is to make a class with interface and cast in your activities.

Comment: I think the second one is easy.

Comment: You have an asynctask, you are using that asynctask in another activity, which prevents you from using the same asynctask in the activity where you need it? This is Basic Java, you can MyCoolAsynctask.execute() from anywhere.

Comment: replace `AppCompactActivity` with `BaseActivity` in all your activities.

Comment: In Base Activity Call Maps Activity

Answer (score 1):

Why do you introduce the `Dummy Activity`. As you are redirecting to the `MapActivity`. Make the API in the background, meanwhile, your map is loaded. Once you get the api response just show that on the map rather than use any other activity.

There is no way to access the data from the previous activity.

One way only to cache the response in the `shared preference` and in map activity you need to get that response. But there are so many cons to use it. I personally definitely not suggest you implement like this.

Just use `async task` in the map activity to make the API call.

Comment: I have done that. It was most feasible for me. But Maps Activity crashes every time I do that. Can you provide me an example of how to make the API call. I think I might be calling it in the wrong way.

Comment: As i don't have such requirement. You can provide me the sample code on git I will fix it over there. @SamratLahiri

Comment: Just edited the Question. Have given the code Please check